# Does having a competency bonus or an insight bonus mean that even with knowledge of that subject, you cant attempt an untrained check?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Recently I got into a debate about an edge case in Rules concerning Racial bonuses, trained Skills, modifiers, and Skill Ranks.

My problem lies with ambiguous rules concerning how Insight, competence, and Racial bonuses are treated by the skill system.

- Insight implies that you've looked into the future to predict whats
  going to happen so that you have the knowledge to succeed at your
  next given task.
- Racial bonuses imply that you grew up doing something so much that it
  is thoroughly a part of your identity.
- Competence bonuses imply magically gifted competence in a given subject

If you have an Insight bonus
   in knowledge you have essentially looked into the future and divined
   the answer to your question. If you have a Racial bonus in Use Magic
   Device, you used wands and other magic items enough to be able to
   gain some degree of proficiency in using them.

In the examples below I find serious fault with how the game handles them, and would like to know why the game treats the cases as they are.

- Case 1:  a Wizard uses a spell to gain an Insight bonus on a Skill roll. Suppose the next Skill roll he makes was a Knowledge check for which he didn't have any Ranks. Presume that the Wizard is Pun-pun, who has a solid +10,000 in his Intelligence modifier and has successfully managed to learn all things in the Universe, but has chosen to leave his Spellcraft skill untrained.  Even with such comprehensive knowledge, does he have to roll to identify an enemy spell being cast?  Knowing all possible spells he knows how to cast them and could identify them as such.  What conditions would make it possible to fail to identify the spell being cast?

  - A gap in his knowledge?
  - Lack of Foresight?
  - A crippling crystal meth addiction?
- Case 2: Race based skills. From their birth a race is taught the art of blacksmithing and crafting magical items, so much so that they get three Item Crafting Feats and can ignore Spell Prerequisites to Craft Magical Items. They get a +8 Racial bonus to Craft, and a +4 Racial Bonus to Use Magic device. They deal with magic items daily, from the day of their birth.

  - Why would they be able to forge a Longsword with this knowledge, but be unable to activate a wand, despite being taught enough by their peers to do so from their birth?
  - Wouldn't life long familiarity with magical items qualify as "Training" for the purposes of skills?
- Case 3: Knowldege checks (based on a point from @DuctTapeAl). In
  order to know anything about a specific monster you have to roll a
  Knowledge check of 10 + that monsters Hit Die. Elves have a Hit Die
  of 1, and Ten plus one is Eleven. To attempt a knowledge check when
  untrained, the DC of the Knowledge check has to be ten or less. Thus,
  *no one who doesn't have access to Knowledge(Local) knows what an Elf
  is, or a Dwarf or a Human for that matter*.  This makes no sense.
- Case 4: "Competence" bonuses granted from items. Wouldn't being
  competent in something mean that you would be able to complete a
  task using the Knowledge and Experience gained from using that magic item? It is
  magically granting you Knowledge about that topic after all.

  - Why wouldn't a cape of +10 Open Lock, which grants a Competence bonus
    to opening locks, not work if you didn't already have a Rank Open
    Lock?
  - Why is the one Rank more important than the +10 bonus?  So when does
    a Skill Bonus stop being a Rank?

Comment: At first I thought this could be salvaged by rewriting it to be one sentence (“Why can't you use a Trained Only skill untrained even when you have a +10,000 to it?”), but really: this is just a rant about the system requiring a skill be Trained to use it. And we don't do questions that are really just raging against the machine. I don't see a way of salvaging this, because the fundamental question is “But *whyyy*?!” and the answer to that is “because.” House rule it or pick a different game if that's not desired. If you're arguing with a fellow player about 3.5e though: sorry, deal with it.

Comment: Let us move the discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29858/room-for-annoying-imp-and-sandwich)

Answer (score 16):

The only thing that counts as skill **ranks** is taking ranks of a skill.  No matter what else you do, your bonus to a trained-only skill doesn't matter unless one of the things providing you with a bonus to that skill is a rank.

By RAW, you cannot make any trained-only skill check unless you have at least 1 rank in a skill.  The relevant rules quote comes from the [Skills section](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/skillDescriptions.htm):

> Trained Only
>   If this notation is included in the skill name line, you must have at least 1 rank in the skill to use it. If it is omitted, the skill can be used untrained (with a rank of 0). If any special notes apply to trained or untrained use, they are covered in the Untrained section (see below).

As that line makes clear, you need a *rank* in a skill in order to be considered trained, no matter your modifier.  One example of this would be a Great Wyrm Gold Dragon with no ranks in Knowledge(Religion).  It has a +11 to Intelligence, but with no actual ranks, it can only make Knowledge(Religion) checks of DC 10 or less.

Some of your examples are not strictly correct.  Racial bonuses don't actually mean that you've been taught something since birth; that's what skill ranks represent.  A racial bonus implies some combination of actual racial advantage (like how an animal might have better-than-human hearing, regardless of training) or living in a culture where that skill was cherished (like a dwarf's bonus to Craft).  The only thing that gives you training is skill ranks.

Insight is actually much less well-defined.  You see it as a form of future sight, I see it as more of an instinct to know what should be done next, or where you should lead your train of thoughts, or how you should pronounce that command word you're trying.  If you're trying to open a lock, it doesn't matter if you're instincts are perfect or not: you can't open a lock unless you at least have some basic knowledge on how to open a lock.

I think the problem here is related to the fact that you're trying to apply narrative logic to mechanical constructs. It's true that competence, racial, and insight bonuses are often (maybe even usually) used to represent specific kinds of benefit, but the simple fact of the rules is that 3.5 doesn't care how awesome you are at an untrained skill. If you have to skill ranks (and the only thing that counts as skill ranks are actual ranks), you can't make the check, high bonus be damned.  The fact that they chose "skill ranks" as the specific thing that unlocks use of a trained skill is just one of several mechanical decisions that the designers could have made, and the fact that "ranks" mean "training enough to do a thing" is largely arbitrary.

One houserule that I typically use is that any trained skill can be used by anyone up to DC 10, and higher DCs take a -10 to the check.  That way, if you're super intelligent, you can make untrained knowledge rolls whether or not you happened to take ranks in that knowledge skill.  It rarely comes into play, but it helps bridge the gap between the simulation implied by D&D 3.x's systems and reality as I interpret it.